# Java JTable/TableModel "addRow" skips every second object

Tags: java, for-loop, jtable, tablemodel, defaulttablemodel

i have a problem with my JTable/TableModel and the addRow - Method.

**Please take a look at these Methods:**

```
public void addToTable()
{
    this.resetTabelModel(new Object[] {"key", "value"});

    for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    {
        System.out.println(i + " --> " + "nothing");
        tableModel.addRow(new Object[] {i, "nothing"});         
    }
}

public void resetTabelModel(Object[] columnIdentifiers)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < this.tableModel.getRowCount(); i++)
    {
        this.tableModel.removeRow(i);
    }
    this.tableModel.setColumnIdentifiers(columnIdentifiers);
}
```

My problem actually is, that the

> System.out.println(i + " --> " + "nothing")

prints the numbers from 0 to 99 correctly.
However...

> tableModel.addRow(new Object[] {i, "nothing"});

just puts 1, 3, 5, ... and so on in my table?

EDIT: Thats what my table looks like!

[image]

I really don´t know what i did wrong and really appreciate your help.

Comment: How are you ascertaining the odd count here?

Comment: i am printing out "i" with System.out.println and then i add the Objects to my table, which i added to my JFrame.

Comment: If the loop iterates 100 times, how is it possible that fewer than 100 rows were inserted?

Comment: Thats what i am asking you ;D

Comment: Look at your reset method: once row 0 is removed, row 1 becomes row 0, and you remove row 1, which is in fact the original row 2.

Comment: @JBNizet This is what I suspected.

Comment: now i get it :) is there any method to delete all the rows at once?

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/table/DefaultTableModel.html#setRowCount-int-

Comment: If your actual `TableModel` is an instance of `DefaultTableModel`, you could empty the underlying `dataVector`. Afterwards call `fireTableDataChanged()`.